# Stress testing a web service. .Net framework

Tags: .net, web-services, stress-testing

I am currently trying to stress a web service based on the .Net framework, so I would appreciate it if you could provide me with some of the tools that are compatible with the .Net framework and your reviews regarding them.

I was reading about the WCat tool, and it seems promising, I just want your reviews regarding it and other tools.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: There lots of question on SO about stress testing. You should review these first.

Comment: I know I checked them, I was asking more about the WCat tool, it was recommended by some colleagues and I couldn't find enough reviews regarding it!
Perhaps the question was't structured well, my bad

Answer (score 1):

We have used [Load Tester](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/) to test many .NET apps, including web services.